# TypeError: res.set is not a function

Tags: express

Im trying to modify my header request but it looks like request object doesnt have the "set" method

```
var shortid = require("shortid");
// To generate a unique ID, use shortid.generate()

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
    req.trace = {
        id: shortid.generate(),
        path: "/tasks",
        timestamp: new Date().getTime(),
    };
    res.headers = {};
    res.headers["x-request-id"] = req.trace.id;
    // NOT WORKING IDK WHY
    //res.set("x-request-id", req.trace.id);
    next();
};
```

Problem

```
TypeError: res.set is not a function
```

Called at

```
app.use("/omega", middleware, omegaRouter);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Express code, `res.set()` and `res.header()` are aliases for each other:

```
res.set =
res.header = function header(field, val) {
  if (arguments.length === 2) {
    var value = Array.isArray(val)
      ? val.map(String)
      : String(val);
 ....
```

As you can see in the [Express source code](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html).

When your code does this:

```
res.headers = {};
```

You are overwriting and messing up the Express method.  If you remove these two lines of code:

```
res.headers = {};
res.headers["x-request-id"] = req.trace.id;
```

Then, your this line:

```
res.set("x-request-id", req.trace.id);
```

should work just fine.

It is unclear what you were trying to do with the two lines of code that access `res.headers` as that is supposed to be a method, not a property you can set.

Comment: @reptilianGK - If this answered your question, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and that will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.